# Пытаюсь изменить значение в памяти, оно ни в какую

Tags: c++, winapi, память

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть программа, в ней пытаюсь изменить значение, пользуюсь артмани для нахождения.
Ели меняю значение, то оно моментально переставляется, что это может быть?
В с++ я все ячейки сразу меняю, не помогает.
В чем проблема может быть, и как обойти?

```
c++

DWORD memory   = 0x00699FD3E95;
    DWORD memory_1 = 0x00699FD3E96;
    DWORD memory_2 = 0x00699FD3E97;
    DWORD memory_3 = 0x00699FD3E98;
    DWORD memory_4 = 0x00699FD3E99;
    DWORD memory_5 = 0x00699FD3E9B;
    DWORD memory_6 = 0x00699FD3E9C;
    DWORD memory_7 = 0x00699FD3E9C;
    DWORD pid = 7428;

    int new = 20;

    int actual;
    int actual1;

    HWND wind = FindWindowA(0, ("SS"));
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(wind, &pid);

    HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    if (!pHandle)
        cout << "Не открылся процесс";
    else
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)memory_1, &actual, sizeof(actual), 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)memory_1, &actual1, sizeof(actual1), 0);

        cout << actual << " : " << actual1 << endl;
        while (true) {
            WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)memory, &new, sizeof(new), 0);
            WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)memory_1, &new, sizeof(new), 0);
            WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)memory_2, &new, sizeof(new), 0);
            WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)memory_3, &new, sizeof(new), 0);
            WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)memory_4, &new, sizeof(new), 0);
            WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)memory_5, &new, sizeof(new), 0);
            WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)memory_6, &new, sizeof(new), 0);
            WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)memory_7, &new, sizeof(new_health), 0);
            
            cout << "Acscess"<<endl;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: я думаю что плохая мысль использовать ключевое слово в качестве имени переменной. попробуй вместо new написать new_value. new это оператор выделения памяти, его нельзя перегружать, и что за код там накомпилировал тебе компилятор тоже вопрос.

Comment: @Yakov, сорри обрезал название переменной, там было new_het

Comment: Проверяйте возвращаемое значение. Если `WriteProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)memory, &new, sizeof(new), 0) == 0 ` напечатайте `GetLastError();` "The function fails if the requested write operation crosses into an area of the process that is inaccessible."

Comment: @AlexGlebe код ошибк 487 т.е не найдено. Я погуглил и понял, что я скорее всего не то нахожу. С помощью чего можно найти адрес?